# Should related Kafka events that manage state be under one event or multiple event per state in a topic

Tags: apache-kafka

The event carried state transfer from user create, user updated, user deleted
Let's assume a practical case:

We have a customer service that publishes UserCreated/UserDeleted,UserCancled events to a customer Kafka topic.

we want to maintain  the order and used one topic but the event types should you have one event ie UserChangeStatus with a status for each use case ie created, deleted or canceled  or Mutiple event per state ie UserCreatedEvent, UserDeletedEvent etc

One event types means in my consumer I get one type and based on the status ill do my business logic, Mutiple event also work and i can use a eventTypeId to split to business logic. I am the only consumer and both ways seems to work but struggle to see online what's the best practices for this case.

Answer (score 0):

That'll work, or you could send tombstone records rather than explicit deleted statuses, and every other value is considered an upsert rather than explicit create/update.

With that design, you can use a compacted topic and Kafka Streams / KsqlDB to build a KTable for all current user information